# How to work with multilingual sites using the full site editor and block themes?

Tags: block-editor, translation

I'm developing a block theme and I need the user to edit the site content with the full site editor in two different languages.

In this situation, what would be the approach to allow the same page to have two versions, each one in a different language?

Comment: Editing content in multiple languages is not a feature of WordPress. There are plugins that add this functionality, so you'd need to ask their authors whether they support full site editing. Any bespoke solution would more than likely require a lot of code well beyond the scope of a single question here.

Answer (score 0):

you either duplicate your website,
or pay multi-money  € ¥ ₪ ¥ $.

The old alternative is to implement multiple languages yourself,
e.g. either a complete duplicate of the website (terrible maintenance)

or a lot of tweaking and customizations (duplicate pages, post types, custom templates per page, where needed, and so forth).

Wordpress developers made it clear by now (20 years) that they don't care about multiple languages, (and some langauges are not even really supported, which is about 1/5 of the world population writing from right to left).

you either pay with money or with (a lot of) time.